# Batch output does not convert version placeholder in result

Tags: batch

So in this batch I want to make

```
set /p pv="2.1.5"
echo Program V : %pv%
set /p rn="0.0.1 [Initial Release] , 0.0.2 [Some Blah]"
echo %rn%
set /p rn2="1.1.3 [New Things, Bug Fix & Improvements] , [2.1.5 Stuff]"
echo %rn2%
```

but it won't work. The output is just

```
2.1.5
Program V
0.0.1 [Initial Release] , 0.0.2 [Some Blah] 
ECHO is off.
1.1.3 [New Things, Bug Fix & Improvements] , [2.1.5 Stuff]
```

My reason for using that is that when I need somewhere else to show the program version, I must not type all of that from the beginning, but I just put the

```
%pv% and %rn% or %rn2% ..
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is simple if you read the output of `set /?` carefully:

```
SET /P variable=[promptString]

The /P switch allows you to set the value of a variable to a line of input
entered by the user.  Displays the specified promptString before reading
the line of input.  The promptString can be empty.
```

Omit all the **/p**s from the **set** commands and be amazed. :)